# How to search using condition OR spring jpa

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am performing a search function in mvc spring. I want to do a search on both Firstname and LastName. If I enter a string in the search box and hit enter, I will do a search in firstName if do not find it performing a search in lastName and vice versa. That means I want to enter a string and do a search for all the fields. Here is my program content.

Employee:

```
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
    private double salary;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeDAO extends  JpaRepository<Employee,Integer>{
    List<Employee> findEmployeeByFirstNameOrLastName(String searchName);

}
```

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search")
    public ModelAndView searchByFirstName(@RequestParam String searchName) {
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("showEmployee");
        return view;
    }
```

View :

```
 <div class="row">
        <form method="get" action="/search">
            <div class="small-3 columns">
                <input type="text" id ="txt" name="searchName" >
            </div>

            <div class="small-5 columns end">
                <button id="button-id" type="submit">Search</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I had run but It can't not search both firstName or LastName. How two search both firstName or lastName with one prameter

Comment: And the issue is...?

Comment: It can't not search both firstName or lastName. I want if i put seach input abc if abc contain firstName spring show me result.If not contain in firstName Spring search in lastName. It mean one param search two field.

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide two field:

```
List<Employee> findEmployeeByFirstNameOrLastName(String firstName, String lastName);
```

Then call it:

```
findEmployeeByFirstNameOrLastName("searchName", "searchName");
```

To get `Employee` whose `firstName` or `lastName` equals to `"searchName"`

The final code look like:

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeDAO extends  JpaRepository<Employee,Integer>{
    List<Employee> findEmployeeByFirstNameOrLastName(String firstName, String lastName);

}


@RequestMapping(value = "/search")
public ModelAndView searchByFirstName(@RequestParam String searchName) {
    ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("showEmployee");
    // Access employeeDAO here, or use employeeService if you using service
    List<Employee> employees = employeeDao.findEmployeeByFirstNameOrLastName(searchName, searchName);
    view.addObject("employees", employees);
    return view;
}
```

For more complex case, you might want to look at JPA Criteria API or QueryDsl to create combination of conditions instead of providing two fields `firstName`, `lastName` like above

Comment: You can't put two @RequestParam same name to controller

Comment: You pass searchName to repository/service, not declare them in controller

Comment: It can't work. I can't put same name into respository or services. You had try it ???

Comment: Thank you. I call repository in searchByFirstName method with same param("searchName") and it work

Comment: Oh ok. I already  edit the answer to show you how it works. Cheer~

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data's derived queries are useful however it is often simpler and clearer to simply specify the query:

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeDAO extends  JpaRepository<Employee,Integer>{

    @Query("select e from Employee e where e.firstName = :searchName 
               or e.lastName = :searchName)
    List<Employee> findEmployeeByFirstNameOrLastName(
             @Param("searchName") String searchName);

}
```

Comment: I had try it but spring throw me error.It doen't not accept  two same ':searchName' in  '@Query'. I don't understand. But when I remove '@query' and pass in two param List<Employee> findEmployeeByFirstNameOrLastName(String firstName,String lastName); and call employeeDao.findEmployeeByFirstNameOrLastName(searchName, searchName) it work for me. But I want thank you help me.

Comment: I think that can be addressed by adding `@Param("searchName")`. See updated answer.